# SQL query grouping by month and weeks using timezone

Tags: sql, date, datetime, group-by

I would like to access the number of inscription by month and by week. I end up with something like

```
select extract(month from date), count(*) 
from inscription
group by extract(month from date);
```

The problem is that this query take the timestamp as a UTC time when I would like to have the stats in my timezone.

An example : if someone subscribe at 1485902400 i.e 31 Jan 23:40:00 in the UTC timezone, the subscription count as being part of the january month when I would like it to be count as february subscription since in my timezone it is 01:40:00.

How could I have my query working with my timezone ?

Moreover this will merge month from different years, how could I separate them ?

Comment: What is your RDBMS (since date / time functions differ)? What the data type of your `date` column?

Comment: It's MySQLand my date colum is a datetime

Comment: Merging the months is an easy problem to solve - either extract the year as well, or select a string that includes both the year and month.

Comment: Something like group by extract(month from year), extract(month from date) ?